# Phpstorm 7 - how to setup closure compiler arguments with my command?

Tags: compiler-construction, closures, installation, phpstorm

I have no idea how can I type in argument for my closure compiler file watcher in phpstorm 7.
Command is:

java -jar compiler.jar --js $FileName$ --create_source_map ./$FileName$-min.js.map --source_map_format=V3 --js_output_file $FileName$-min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... Something like the following:

```
Program: <path to your compiler.jar>/compiler.jar 

Arguments: --js $FileName$ --create_source_map ./$FileNameWithoutExtension$-min.js.map --source_map_format=V3 --js_output_file $FileNameWithoutExtension$-min.js

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output Paths: $FileNameWithoutExtension$-min.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$-min.js.map
```

Comment: also make sure to uncheck 'Create output file from stdout' option